# Work done by a field along a circle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, vector-fields, greens-theorem

I have the vector field

$$F(x, y) = (\frac{-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2} + \frac{y}{(x+1)^2+y^2}, \frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2+y^2} + \frac{-x-1}{(x+1)^2+y^2})$$

Using Green's Theorem I want to calculate the work done by $F$ along a circle of the form $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$.

How should I do it since the denominator is zero at $(1, 0)$ and $(-1, 0)$? I know that theoretically I could divide the region in 2 parts, but how do I set it up analytically in order to compute the work?

Comment: @boojum yes it does.  Green's theorem requires that the function have continuous partial derivatives inside the region.  The function is conservative, so you can modify it if you wish to any curve that contains this singularity.  In my mind, this problem is a little bit like having a singularity in complex analysis, and without working this out, I am willing to wager you get a multple of $2\pi$ out of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Green's theorem because you don't have continuous partial derivatives.

Let $G = (\frac {-y}{(x-1)^2 + y^2},\frac {x-1}{(x-1)^2+y^2})$
and $H = (\frac {-y}{(x+1)^2 + y^2},\frac {x+1}{(x+1)^2+y^2})$

$F = G-H$

It is easier to check $G$ and $H$ independently to see that they are curl free.

$H$ does have continuous partials over the region, so the integral of a conservative field over a closed curve is zero.

Now we can parameterize the curve and integrate $G.$

$\int_0^{2\pi} (-\sin x,\cos x)\cdot (-\sin x. \cos x)\ dx = 2\pi$

Comment: All right, thank you for the discussion:  I hadn't run into an example with a singularity in the interior of the closed curve.  It's messy to work out, but $ \ \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} \ = \ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \ \  $ for $ \ \mathbf{F} (x,y) \ \ , \ $ which is completely misleading here.

Comment: I'm starting to understand it better with your answer! So I can check them independently and understand that the work done by one of them would be zero. So If some terms of a field do no work along a curve I can not account for them; that makes sense!

Comment: If the singularity lies within my curve, how would I proceed in order to apply Green's Theorem? Because it could only be used for Fields of $C^1$. Could I, as an example, "cut" the singularity by parameterising another curve, counterclockwise, around the undefined point and add both integrals? As the new curve is counterclockwise would the result for the integral be negative?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to use Green's theorem. To perturb slightly the vector field defining as

$F_{1}=\dfrac{-y}{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}+\epsilon}$+$\dfrac{y}{(x+1)^{2}+y^{2}}$

$F_{2}$=$\dfrac{x-1}{(x-1)^{2}+\epsilon+y^{2}}$$-$$\dfrac{x+1}{(x+1)^{2}+y^{2}}$

in order to avoid singularities. Set $F_{2}=Q,\,\,F_{1}=P$.

We get $Q_{x}-P_{y}=\dfrac{2\epsilon}{[(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}+\epsilon]^{2}}$

Changing to polar coordinates by $x=1+rcos\theta,\,\,y=sin\theta$

we obtain  $\,\,\,2\epsilon\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{(r^{2}+\epsilon)^{2}}rdrd\theta$

which is equal to : $2\pi\dfrac{1}{1+\epsilon}$ and taking $\epsilon\to 0$ we get $2\pi$.

It seems that it is like having a removable singularity of the field!!

Answer (score 0):

The circle can be parametrized as

$ r = (1 + \cos(t) , \sin(t) ) \hspace{20pt} t \in [0, 2 \pi) $

and

$\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{F_1} + \mathbf{F_2} $

where

$\mathbf{F_1} = (   - \sin(t) , \cos(t) ) $

and

$ \mathbf{F_2} = ( \dfrac{\sin(t)}{ 5 + 4 \cos(t)  } , - \dfrac{ 2 + \cos(t) }{ 5 + 4 \cos(t) } )$

The work is linear,

$W_1 = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \mathbf{F_1} \cdot (-\sin(t), \cos(t) ) \ dt = 2 \pi $

$W_2 = \displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} \mathbf{F_2} \cdot (-\sin(t), \cos(t) ) \ dt \\
= \displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} \dfrac{ - 1 - 2 \cos (t) }{5 + 4 \cos(t) } \ dt $

Let $z = \tan(\frac{t}{2})$ , then $dz = \frac{1}{2} \sec^2(\frac{t}{2}) \ dt = \frac{1}{2}(z^2 + 1) $,  $\cos(t) = 2 \cos^2(\frac{t}{2}) - 1 = \dfrac{2}{z^2 + 1} - 1 = \dfrac{1 - z^2}{1 + z^2} $

Hence,

$W_2 = \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{- 1 - 2 (1 - z^2) }{5 (z^2 + 1) + 4(1 - z^2) } dz \\ 
= \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{2 z^2 - 3}{z^2 + 9} dz \\
= \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{2(z^2 + 9) - 21 }{z^2 + 9}dz \\
=\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2} \bigg[ 2 z - 7 \tan^{-1}(\frac{z}{3}) \bigg] $

Plugging in $z$ and evaluating over $t \in [0, 2\pi) $ gives the value $ 2 \pi$

Therefore, the total work is

$ W = W_1 + W_2 = 2 \pi + 2 \pi = 4 \pi $